# Plotting parametric curves

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot some parametric curves, however I always get an an error saying "Dimension is too large".  Is there any way to fix this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.2]
\draw[very thin,color=gray,step=.5cm,dashed] (-8,-8) grid (4,4);
\draw[<->, blue] (-8,0) -- (4,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[<->, blue] (0,-8) -- (0,4) node[left] {$y$};
\draw [red, thick,  domain=-10:1.1, samples=40] 
 plot ({\x^3-3*\x}, {3*\x^2-9} );
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The numbers are too big, just switch to pgfplots and it would work just fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{tkz-fct}  

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,xstep=2,ymin=-10,ymax=4,ystep=2]
  \tkzGrid[sub]
  \tkzAxeX[step=2]
  \tkzAxeY[step=2]
  \tkzFctPar[samples=400,domain=-pi:pi]{t**3-3*t}{3*t**2-9}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 24):

The problem was with the line

```
\draw [red, thick,  domain=-10:1.1, samples=40] 
 plot ({\x^3-3*\x}, {3*\x^2-9} );
```

In particular, your `domain=-10:1.1` was too big. You could just change it, or even better, use [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) for your task, which is what I've demonstrated below.

Note the use of `\pgfplotsset` to set global settings in the preamble.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
                    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
                    axis line style={<->,color=blue}, % arrows on the axis
                    xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
                    ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
            }}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-8,xmax=4,
            ymin=-8,ymax=4,
            grid=both,
            ]
            \addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=50]({x^3-3*x},{3*x^2-9}); 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

With PSTricks just for fun!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{unit=5mm,plotpoints=1000,algebraic}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-20,-12)(21,21)
    \psaxes[Dx=5,Dy=5]{->}(0,0)(-20,-12)(20,20)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2\pslinewidth]{-3}{3}{t^3-3*t|3*t^2-9}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]