# How to draw slope fields with all the possible solution curves in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, equations

Sorry, I have no code to submit, mostly because I have no idea how to do this.

I want to type up my homework (I can do the homework by hand) and I am looking for a simple method that I can use repetitively on different equations; without having to code each equation; to make/produce/draw the slope field of that equation.

Currently, I have typed up the rest of my homework with latex, but have no good example from the internet to follow.  I want to put the slope fields for both `$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=2x$` 
and 
`$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=x\sqrt{x}$` into my homework.

My system is Fedora 19.

Any suggestions?

ps. sorry if this is a poor quality question.  I just used the suggested tags.

Comment: @texenthusiast Honestly, I have no idea which tags to use, so I used the suggested one.

Comment: Fixed my question.  You have $\frac{dy}{dx}=$some equation.  Draw a graph of all the possible solution curves.

Comment: I hope this Q: [Plotting parametric curves](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65719/15717) and linked questions might help ? Please update the Q with comment info "Draw a graph of all the possible solution curves"

Comment: pst-ode package is written for solving your problem.

Comment: @Marienplatz, could you post an example? I'll upvote it like the GOD you are!

Comment: @MaoYiyi: `pst-ode` example is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139140

Comment: An alternative is to make the plots in an external program such as Matlab and to import them as a TikZ image in LaTeX.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use PGFPlots' `quiver` plot style for drawing the vector fields.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "all possible solution curves", since that would just cover the whole plot area. I just drew one possible solution for each equation, all others would just be vertically shifted versions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\pgfplotsset{ % Define a common style, so we don't repeat ourselves
    MaoYiyi/.style={
        width=0.6\textwidth, % Overall width of the plot
        axis equal image, % Unit vectors for both axes have the same length
        view={0}{90}, % We need to use "3D" plots, but we set the view so we look at them from straight up
        xmin=0, xmax=1.1, % Axis limits
        ymin=0, ymax=1.1,
        domain=0:1, y domain=0:1, % Domain over which to evaluate the functions
        xtick={0,0.5,1}, ytick={0,0.5,1}, % Tick marks
        samples=11, % How many arrows?
        cycle list={    % Plot styles
                gray,
                quiver={
                    u={1}, v={f(x)}, % End points of the arrows
                    scale arrows=0.075,
                    every arrow/.append style={
                        -latex % Arrow tip
                    },
                }\\
                red, samples=31, smooth, thick, no markers, domain=0:1.1\\ % The plot style for the function
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={f(\x) = 2*\x;} % Define which function we're using
]
\begin{axis}[
    MaoYiyi, title={$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=2x$}
]
\addplot3 (x,y,0);
\addplot {x^2+0.15}; % You need to find the antiderivative yourself, unfortunately. Good exercise!
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={f(\x) = \x*sqrt(\x);}
]
\begin{axis}[
    MaoYiyi,
    title={$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=x\sqrt{x}$},
    ytick=\empty
]
\addplot3 (x,y,0);
\addplot +[domain=0.001:1.1] {x^(2.5)/2.5+0.15};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set up the `y` domain depending of `x`, for example, `y domain=0 : cos(x)`?

Answer (score 6):

Sage includes the python code for stream lines, a much prettier way to draw stream lines (also called flow lines, or integral curves) of a vector field in the plane.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
    An elegant plot of the stream lines of the vector field \(\sin x \partial_x + \cos y \partial y\).
    \begin{sagesilent}
        x, y = var('x y')
    \end{sagesilent}
    \begin{center}
        \sageplot[width=\textwidth]{streamline_plot((sin(x), cos(y)), (x,-3,3), (y,-3,3))}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: stream lines of a vector field]

Comment: This is beautiful and elegant. I am using this

Answer (score 5):

As Charles0349 said above, it is natural way to draw slope field. Moreover, we can control the length of velocity vector of the vector field.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=\x+\y;}]
\def\xmax{3} \def\xmin{-3}
\def\ymax{3} \def\ymin{-3}
\def\nx{15}  \def\ny{15}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\hx}{(\xmax-\xmin)/\nx}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hy}{(\ymax-\ymin)/\ny}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\nx}
\foreach \j in {0,...,\ny}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}
\draw[teal,-stealth,shift={({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}] (0,0)--(.1,.1*\yprime);
}

% a solution y=(yo+1)e^x-x-1
\def\yo{1}
\draw[magenta] plot[domain=\xmin:1] (\x,{(\yo+1)*exp(\x)-\x-1});

\draw[->] (\xmin-.5,0)--(\xmax+.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,\ymin-.5)--(0,\ymax+.5) node[above left] {$y$};
\draw (current bounding box.north) node[above]
{Slope field of \quad $y'=x+y$.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=\x+\y;}]
\def\xmax{3} \def\xmin{-3}
\def\ymax{3} \def\ymin{-3}
\def\nx{15}
\def\ny{15}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\hx}{(\xmax-\xmin)/\nx}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\hy}{(\ymax-\ymin)/\ny}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\nx}
\foreach \j in {0,...,\ny}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yprime}{f({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}
\draw[blue,shift={({\xmin+\i*\hx},{\ymin+\j*\hy})}] 
(0,0)--($(0,0)!2mm!(.1,.1*\yprime)$);
}

% a solution y=(yo+1)e^x-x-1
\def\yo{1}
\draw[magenta] plot[domain=\xmin:.9] (\x,{(\yo+1)*exp(\x)-\x-1});

\draw[->] (\xmin-.5,0)--(\xmax+.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,\ymin-.5)--(0,\ymax+.5) node[above left] {$y$};
\draw (current bounding box.north) node[above]
{Slope field of \quad $y'=x+y$.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code only produces the first two images. Is the difference between the second and the last only that you added a parameter ```->``` to the ```draw``` command?

Comment: Also, how can I solutions with asymptotes and still main the different sizes of vector arrows?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik in the last picture, all arrows have the same length. In the same manner, you can draw with Asymptote. (although Áymptote have the slopefield module for that)

Comment: @ViktorGlombik You can make a new question (click to Ask Question button) with tag Asymptote

Comment: This is a really nice answer. It could be improved bij adding comment lines to the code. This makes is easier for future readers to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not super good at LaTeX, but I think the following is a pretty straight-forward approach. This is a slope field for dy/dx = x + y.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={diff(\x,\y) = \x+\y;}]
        \draw[->] (-5.2, 0) -- (5.2, 0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-6.1) -- (0, 6.1) node[above] {$y$};
            \foreach \i in {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5}
            \foreach \j in {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4, 5}
            {
                \draw[thick] ( {\i -0.1}, {\j - diff(\i, \j) *0.1}) --  ( {\i +0.1}, {\j  + diff(\i, \j) *0.1});
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]