# Plotting parametric curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm trying to make a parametric graph, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
                    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
                    axis line style={<->,color=blue}, % arrows on the axis
                    xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
                    ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
            }}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-8,xmax=6,
            ymin=-8,ymax=6,
            grid=both,
            ]
            \addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=50]({2.5\sin^2(-5x)2^{\cos(\cos(4.28(2.3x)))}},{2.5\sin(\sin(-5x))\cos^2(4.28(2.3x))}); 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you trying to plot?  The `domain=-3:3,samples=50` is an option to `\addplot` which should be enclosed as `[domain=-3:3,samples=50]` and in your code`\addplot` has no argument giving it a file of data or a function to plot.  `\addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=50] {x};` for example will plot `y=x` from `-3` to `+3`.

Comment: @DaiBowen an answer? :)

Comment: If I use the correct syntax for the functions to be plotted, I just get a black blob over the x-axis.

Comment: You're also making the mistake of using macros intended for typesetting (`\cos`,`\sin`) instead of the mathematical functions defined by `pgf` for calculations (`cos`,`sin`, no backslash). And finally, you need to explicitly add multiplication, so `5*x`, not `5x`.

Answer (score 2):

The `domain=-3:3,samples=50` is an option to `\addplot` which should be enclosed as `[domain=-3:3,samples=50]` and in your code`\addplot` has no argument giving it a file of data or a function to plot. `\addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=50] {x};` for example will plot `y=x` from `-3 to +3`.

In order to plot parametric curves rather than giving `{x}`, `\addplot` should receive `\addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=50]({x^3-3*x},{3*x^2-9});` or to work with some variable `t` rather than `x` (to me at least this feels more intuitive!), `\addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=50,variable=\t]({t^3-3*t},{3*t^2-9});` will plot `x(t)=t^3-3d` and `y(t)=3t^2-9` for `t` between `-3` and `3`.

See [Plotting parametric curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65719/106162), in particular [cmhughes' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65732/106162) for a full example of parametric plots with `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't input the functions to be plotted in TeX syntax, but in a way that allows the computation.

Recall that `cos` and `sin` take their argument in degrees, so you have to transform the argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={
    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
    axis line style={<->,color=blue}, % arrows on the axis
    xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
    ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-5,xmax=5,
  ymin=-5,ymax=5,
  grid=both,
]
  \addplot[domain=-30:30,samples=100,variable=\t](%
    {2.5 * (sin(deg(-5*t)))^2 * 2^(cos(deg(cos(deg(4.28*2.3*t)))))},%
    {2.5 * (sin(deg(sin(deg(-5*t))))) * (cos(deg(4.28*2.3*t)))^2}%
  ); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Increasing the number of samples produces a big black blob.