# Starting LaTex, drawing a metric ball

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, math-mode, draw

I'm trying to represent balls in `radial metric` using `pgfplots` and `tikz`.

`Radial metric` is a `metric d` in `R^2` given by:

```
d( (a,b), (x,y) ) = p( (a,b), (x,y) ) if bx = ay

d( (a,b), (x,y) ) = p( (a,b), (0,0) ) + p( (0,0), (x,y) ) if bx =/= ay
```

Where `p` is the euclidean distance, so you can rewrite it as follows:

```
d( (a,b), (x,y) ) = sqrt( (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 ) if bx = ay

d( (a,b), (x,y) ) = sqrt(a^2 + b^2) + sqrt(x^2 + y^2) if bx =/= ay
```

I've graphicated in desmos, you can see the form of any ball by any center of radius [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kcrvrzobuq)

I'd like to write a general expression for those balls, in such a way that if I want to plot two different balls, in order to plot the second one, the only thing I have to do is to change the center and the radius of the first one.

I've read some posts about plotting an implicit function using `tikz`, but I can't see the way that could help me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: related: [Plotting parametric curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65719/138900)

Comment: @TobiBS Thank you for the advice, I did not know anything about this community rules. And I didn't know which would be a good start point learning to draw in LaTeX and LaTeX itself. "vi pa" answer gave me a start point, and I'm very thankful you didn't erase my question. Now, I investigate my own problem and present a MWE in all my questions. So, another time, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a first try.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,math}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.misc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\newcommand{\dcircl}[3]{
\tikzmath{
\myr = #1;
\mya = #2;
\myb = #3;
\p1 = ifthenelse(\mya==0, 0, \mya + sqrt((\mya^2 * \myr^2)/(\mya^2 + \myb^2)));
\q1 = ifthenelse(\mya==0, \myb + \myr, \p1 * (\myb / \mya));
\p2 = ifthenelse(\mya==0, 0, \mya - sqrt((\mya^2 * \myr^2)/(\mya^2 + \myb^2)));
\q2 = ifthenelse(\mya==0, \myb - \myr, \p2 * (\myb / \mya));
\d1 = veclen(\mya,\myb);
\radius = ifthenelse(\d1 < \myr, \myr - \d1, 0);
}
\draw[dashed,green!50!black,fill=green!80!black,opacity=0.4] (0,0) circle[radius=\radius];
\node[inner sep=2pt,cross out,draw] at (axis cs:\mya,\myb){};
\draw[red,opacity=0.5] (axis cs:\p1,\q1) -- (axis cs:\p2,\q2);
\filldraw[fill=white,draw=red,draw opacity=0.7] (axis cs:\p1,\q1) circle[radius=2pt];
\filldraw[fill=white,draw=red,draw opacity=0.7] (axis cs:\p2,\q2) circle[radius=2pt];
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
axis y line=center,
axis x line=center,
axis equal,
xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-6.5, ymax=6.5
]
\dcircl{3.2}{1.7}{0.8}%dcircl{r}{a}{b}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]